# Paypal integration GET to POST conversion in symfony 2

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, omnipay, symfony-2.7

I am quite new to PayPal integration on my site I have integrated PayPal by express checkout by using GET method but PayPal is discontinuing GET call so how I can convert GET to POST call?

My project in Symfony 2.7 and I used omnipay bundle for PayPal integration, Express gateway type is used.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the PayPal Express omnipay gateway (PayPal_Express) then all of the calls in that gateway are already POST calls.  There is no need to convert GET calls to POST calls.

In general I would advise use of the PayPal_REST gateway rather than PayPal_Express, the calls are more up to date and the documentation is better.  You can go into your developer site for PayPal and obtain API keys for REST which you can use alongside your Express keys while you change over.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, you literally save my day. In next project surely I will use PayPal_REST gateway. can you share any example of PayPal_REST gateway it will be helpful for me to understand and use in a project

Comment: Hi, if you check the class docblocks for PayPal_REST you will see that there are many examples there.  There are docblocks in the gateway class as well as the message classes (e.g. AbstractRestRequest.php).